# showing a html format string on browser in java

Tags: java

I have problem about showing a string in html format on my browser in java. Here I have a java string like this

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H2>403 Forbidden</H2>
</P></H3>You need permission for this service</BODY></HTML>
```

With this method "rep.formForbidden()", I get this html format string, so I need it show it on my browser. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a plain Servlet, or some specific java web framework like Spring MVC?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking but you probably want to fix your HTML. You have closing tags for `p` and `h3` but no opening tags.

Comment: I have a program that is working like proxy. When I enter my browser, it sends a request to this program. I'm displaying the url that user wants to visit. If the url is forbidden, I want to show this html format string on my browser. I don't use any external framework or servlet.

Comment: I'am asking how I can show this string on my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this whole string:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H2>403 Forbidden</H2>
</P></H3>You need permission for this service</BODY></HTML>
```

to be visible in your browser as it is, you need to wrap it with `<code>` or `<pre>` HTML tags .

> I'am asking how I can show this string on my browser

Wrap it like this:

```
<pre>
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H2>403 Forbidden</H2>
    </P></H3>You need permission for this service</BODY></HTML>
</pre>
```